# How to get the polygon points when a marker is placed on it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the polygon points when a marker is placed inside the google map. My javascript code looks something like this

```
function draw_map_initialize() {
 var mapHeight = '400px';
// Set default height to  Maps Containers
$('#map-canvas').css('height', mapHeight);

// Initialize map with markers(47.53187912201915, 7.705222390807307)
mymap = new GMaps({
    div: '#map-canvas',
    lat: 47.53187912201915,
    lng: 7.705222390807307,
    zoom: 20,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'

});
map = mymap
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingControlOptions: {

        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
        drawingModes: [
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
        ]
    },
    //drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    markerOptions: {
        draggable: true                   
    },

    polylineOptions: {
        editable: true
    },
    map: map
});
}
```

I have another method which draws a polygon when a map is loaded it looks some thing like this

```
function getAreasForCompany(idcompany) {
var area_values;
$.ajax({
    url: url_prefix + "getAreasForCompany",
    data: ({
        'idcompany': idcompany,
        'as_json': 1
    }),
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var result = {};
        var count = 1;
        var path = [];
        /* The for loop is to change the JSON data structure. New JSON structure to loop through the DB values to iterate the polygon. 
           The New JSON structure is to avoid naming restrictions of a polygon while storing  */
        for (var key in data) {
            obj = {
                'name': key,
                'coords': data[key]
            };
            result['area' + count++] = obj;
        }

        var company_area;
        map = mymap;
        /* Here we iterate the stored area points with the dynamically created result['area'+count++] */
        for (key in result) {
            company_area = map.drawPolygon({
                paths: result[key].coords,
                title: result[key].name,
                draggable: true,
                editable: true,
                strokeColor: 'black',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                click: clickFun(this)
            });

       }
    },
    error: function(data, status, e) {
            alert(e);
        } // $("#zones").html(dataJson[i].coords);

});
}
```

Now I want to know that how to get the polygon points as soon as marker placed on it or Is it Possible to get the polygon points when marker is clicked?

Thanks

Comment: where's the code that draws the polygon?

Comment: @@ducan: I edited my post in which you can see a getAreasForCompany() which draws the polygon.

Comment: What does "something like this" mean? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Where does `sac_handler_map` come from?

Comment: @@geocodezip: sorry its mymap not sac_handler_map. which comes from function draw_map_initialize()